# app delegate not being called, project.pbxproj corrupt

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, xcode7

Hi guys I have a very weird issue and I really need help. 
I was trying to commit from Xcode and opened source tree (I use sourceTree to merge changes from branches) while the commit was being performed in Xcode. SourceTree is another git manager, Xcode went crazy when SourceTree asked for my credentials and I entered wrong password. Suddenly Xcode 7 crashed and when I reopened, my project was not there, it had dissapeared. I managed to recuperate files and code, but the configuration file `project.pbxproj` was missing. Not even present in github. 
I managed to recuperate an old version of this file. 
When I reopened the project, I had to add some files again that were there in the project but weren't detected. I finally managed to compile, but now when I launch my app, my App delegate is not being called. The app freezes at splash screen. I think it is probably because of this file. 
Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Least effort is probably to create a new project and migrate the code and such to the new project. Might be save you time/money?

Comment: No problem at all! Any help I can give to less the burden of the crappy tool Xcode *can* be, I like to give. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you fixed it, a suggestion for future problems like this one.

Check if the main.m file is imported and if it's calling the app delegate.

Take a look at this https://github.com/appsquickly/XcodeEditor
And this https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes